# Detect Shift + F10 or Context menu button

Tags: c#

In my C# app, i want to detect when the user presses the context menu button in keyboard. This button is on right side of key board in between the Windows and Ctrl keys.

Also need to figure out when user presses Shift + F10, which is another short cut for showing context menu.

How can i do that?

I am capturing the key presses inside a function.

```
private void keypressed(Object obj, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will display a number for any key combination you type in the form's header line. Just find out the corresponding number (for shift+F10 it is 65657) and react within a switch. Context Menu is 93. Some keys could differ with the keyboard layout...

Just paste this in any windows-form-class you like:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        int KeyAsInt=(int)keyData;
        this.Text = KeyAsInt.ToString();
        switch (KeyAsInt) {
            case 65657:
                MessageBox.Show("Heureka!");
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```