# # button not working in Key Down c#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, motorola

On press of '#' on my MC45 Device i want to call a method.
My code looks like:

```
void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int keyValue = e.KeyValue;
    switch (keyValue)
    {
        case 16: // Do Something
        {

        }
    }
}
```

the Key Value for '#' is 16.
So when i press '#' it works fine but a subsequent call on KeyDown happens with key value '51' every time.
Why ?? How do i stop this subsequent call ??

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/564338/5089204 or think about `ProcessCmdKey`.

Comment: Here I answered a related question, might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33355205/5089204

Comment: My question is why does a subsequent call with keyValue 51 happen, just after the key down event of #.?

Comment: The KeyValue is very much depending on your actual keyboard layout. Actually I do not know your keys 16 and 51. In my system there are other values... The reason for the second event could be something like "send an `arrow left` to jump to the next control. But I cannot reproduce this here...

Comment: 16 is the Shift key, 51 is the 3 key.  Yes, many keyboard layouts require pressing Shift+3 to produce "#".  Using KeyDown to detect characters like # is a pretty bad idea, it should be done with KeyPress instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant is right, the '#' key events are Shift+3 (US keyboard layout).

For detecing the '#' key press you should use KeyPress event and not  KeyDown/KeyUp.

One further possible pitfall: on newer Windows Mobile 6.5.3 the # and * may be mapped to VK_TSTAR and VK_TPOUND and these are mapped to VK_F8 and VK_F9. See winuserm.h:

```
#define VK_TSTAR    VK_F8               // *           
#define VK_TPOUND   VK_F9               // #
```

The result of this maybe that your app does not see those * and # presses as they are send as F8 and F9 by the OS.